# Renaming cpack automatic target

Tags: cmake, cpack

When you `INCLUDE(CPack)` in a `CMakeLists.txt` file, it adds a target named `package` to the generated build files. You can configure a lot of things about that generated target and how it operates, but I can't seem to find a way to change the name of the target itself; i.e., instead of a generated `Makefile` containing a target named `package`, I'd like it to contain one named (for example) `bundle` instead. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake only adds the default `package` target if a package config file named `CPackConfig.cmake` exists in the outermost binary build directory. By forcing the CPack module to generate the package file under a different name, you can prevent the `package` target from being created:

```
set (CPACK_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BundleConfig.cmake")
include(CPack)
```

You can manually add a `bundle` target then:

```
add_custom_target(bundle
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND}" 
    "-C" "$<CONFIGURATION>" "--config" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BundleConfig.cmake")
```

This is also true for the default `package_source` target. Use the variable `CPACK_SOURCE_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE` to override the default package configuration file name `CPackSourceConfig.cmake`.

Comment: When I try this approach, the command `cmake --build . --target bundle` calls cpack immediately, without building the targets. I guess some dependency needs to be set, but I cannot figure out how.